# padding-right on :first-line using CSS

Tags: html, css

I was reading through MDN's page for [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) on my phone and noticed what I thought was a textual error: there should be a comma after the `[` in the final argument of the syntax.

[image: Syntax missing comma]

I went to edit the page, and discovered the comma does exist; it's hidden by the  Copy to Clipboard button.  (Oddly, despite `white-space: pre`, Chrome iOS treats it like `pre-wrap`, while Chrome desktop does not.)

The ideal solution for this (barring a fix to Chrome iOS) would be a CSS style that sets the `padding-right` of the first line.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: /* ... */) {
/* or some other way to determine we're in a mobile browser */
  .code-example pre:first-line {
    padding-right: 41px;
  }
}
```

This, however, seems to be ignored.  Am I doing something wrong or--as I suspect--is this simply impossible?

Another, easier if inelegant, solution would be to set the Copy to Clipboard button's style to

```css
.code-example .copy-icon {
  display: block;
  margin-right: -16px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  float: right;
}
```

and move the `<button>` inside the `<pre>`.  But, much like `<table>` en lieu of `display: grid`, `float` is out of vogue.

Plus, without a conditional check for mobile browsers, this change would alter the behavior of desktop/non-buggy mobile browsers:

[image: On desktop with updated styles]

Despite `white-space: pre; overflow: auto`, the browser is rendering line-wrap.

Assuming `:first-line { padding-right }` is unsupported, is there another way to achieve the same effect with either CSS or a JavaScript hack?

---

Note: I *did* search for a duplicate question, but every result was about indenting the first line of a paragraph, the solution to which is `:first-line { text-indent }`.

---

#### Update

I *suppose* given any solution that detects the browser must, by definition, detect the browser, we could just detect buggy browsers using `navigator.userAgent`, and then manipulate the DOM and apply `float: right` to the button.  Kinda nasty, though.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the MDN page you've referred to, I noticed there is a `<code>` element inside the `<pre>`. Hence, you could do the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: /* ... */) {
/* or some other way to determine we're in a mobile browser */
  .code-example pre code {
    display: block;
    max-width: 90%;
  }
}
```

That way, the Copy to Clipboard button wouldn't overlap the code.

Comment: Wouldn't that limit the width of the whole thing, not just the first line?

Comment: Yes, it would. However, I don't see any problem there, since the visual difference is less perceptible than if we applied the style you suggested to the Copy to Clipboard button. Using JavaScript, you could even apply that style only in buggy browsers.